# Paste figures avoiding formulas on target

Tags: excel, paste, formulas, vba

I have a macro to copy and paste values into different columns in my spreadsheet. On the target columns I have some formulas that I need to avoid to override when the macro paste the values as I actually want the formula to calculate the new values. I have a code created already, but I would really appreciate you help adding the condition to avoid pasting where there are formulas on the target.

```
Sub RawDataNew()
'
' RawDataNew Macro
' To move validated to previous week on raw data tab
'
    Range("$B$17:$AQ$2572").AutoFilter Field:=6
    Range("Z18:AB2572").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AU18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("H18:H2572").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AR18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O18:O2572").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AS18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("W18:W2572").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AX18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("X18:X2572").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AY18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("G4").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("G4").Value = Date

    Range("G5").Value = Environ("username")
'
End Sub
```

Comment: What language is this?  What spreadsheet?

Comment: Maybe using the excel tag you get more help

Comment: Hi Scott it is VBA

Answer (score 0):

The paste method you're using `Paste:=xlPasteValues` is only pasting the values; if you want formulas as well as values, you'll need `Paste:=xlPasteAll`.

If you ONLY want formulas, you'll need `Paste:=xlPasteFormulas`

Please refer to [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel) for other optional parameters

Another suggestion is using the `=` method ie.
    `Range("A1").value = Range("B1").value`
As the copy/paste method is very slow, especially when you have as much data as you're using here now. Also, you'll get all the extra formatting from the copied cells, which can be quite annoying to deal with

Comment: Thank you Maldred but I actually need to paste it as values, the challenge is that on the column where I paste it there is a formula that I need to keep it. If I paste values, it will override it and if I paste all it will keep it but the rest of the data will be formulas providing data I don't need.
The target in the macro needs to have an exception to avoid pasting values in the cell where is a formula, but I don't know how to add it to my macro